# What's the practical difference of a wait process and a sense process?

Tags: vhdl

All the VHDL-tutorials I've read mentions that one can use a sense process and a wait process, but I have been unable to grasp the difference.

That is:

```
Waitproc: process
    wait until clock ...
end process
```

Versus

```
Sense-proc: process (clock)
    if rising_edge(clock) then
    ...
end process
```

To me, these to seems do the same thing but obviously there must be a difference.

When should I use which one, and why?

Comment: Waitproc and Sense-proc are just optional labels.

Comment: Uh, yes, but the waitproc lacks a sensitivity-list while the other has one, as well as the wait-statement.

Comment: It looks like two ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: Wait doesn’t synthesize. So if you want to put your VHDL in hardware, you need to use the latter.

Comment: Interesting. Follow-up: When does one want to use VHDL and not put it in hardware?

Comment: In testbenches and model simulation (trying out an idea or principle before designing the real one).

Comment: Waits are usually used in testbenches. Not sure all wait will synthesise. They dont usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure VHDL, there is no difference between a process with a sensistivity list (a,b,..x) and a process without one but with a '`wait on a,b,..x;`' as its final line.

So no difference between:

```
  pFirst : process(a,b) is
  begin
    ...
  end process pFirst;

  pSecond : process is
  begin
    ...
    wait on a,b;
  end process pSecond;
```

You will almost always see the first form used because it is synthesizable. The wait statement is not.

Note that pSecond has the '`wait on`' statement at the end of the process. At the start of simulation, all processes are carried out once, regardless of what they are sensitive to. The position of the '`wait on`' statement in pSecond ensures that it does not pause for its sensitive signals until its end.

The second form is useful in testbenches where you want a non-synthesizable process to include time delays as well as sensitivity to signal(s). A process with a sensitivity list will not allow a `'wait for n us;`' statement but one without a sensitivity list will.

So you can't do:

```
  pThird : process(a) is
  begin
    if falling_edge(a) then
      wait for 10 ns;
      cs  <=  not cs;
      wait for 2 ns;
    end if;
  end process pThird;
```

but you can do:

```
  pFourth : process is
  begin
    if falling_edge(a) then
      wait for 10 ns;
      cs  <=  not cs;
      wait for 2 ns;
    end if;
    wait on a;
  end process pFourth;
```

I find the latter very useful for writing bus master or bus slave models and so on.

Comment: Distinguishing the two types of processes is superimposed where the VHDL standard makes no distinction. Processes suspend and resume in wait statements. A process with a sensitivity list has a single implicit `wait on sensitivity_list;` as the last statement (IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement). Certain wait statement use can be synthesized (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) 6.1.3.2 Edge-sensitive storage using a single wait statement, 6.1.3.4 Edge-sensitive storage with multiple waits). These are likely still supported by all synthesis tools.